# Why isn't my text field being added to the page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, drop-down-menu

I'm working on the interactivity of a simple HTML form.

Specifically, there is a dropdown select box for job roles. If 'other' is selected, then a text field should appear, asking the user to be more specific.

I'm a beginner and want to do this without jQuery.

Here is a snippet of the HTML I am working with:

```
<fieldset class="basic">         
        <legend>Basic Info</legend>

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">

        <label for="mail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">

        <label>Job Role</label>
        <select id="title" name="user_title">
          <option value="full-stack js developer">Full Stack JavaScript Developer</option>
          <option value="front-end developer">Front End Developer</option>
          <option value="back-end developer">Back End Developer</option>
          <option value="designer">Designer</option>          
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>  
        </select>           
      </fieldset>
```

My intuition tells me to first build the text field and add it's attributes.

I will then use an if condition to test whether or not the selected option is 'other'. If it is, then I will append the newly created text field to the page.

This hasn't been working so far. To try and debug this, I have tried console logging the elements I am trying to work with. I don't think I'm understanding how this works as it's printing out 'undefined' and 'null'.

Here is my JS:

// TASK: Add interactivity to form

```
'use strict';

// Hold DOM elements for easy access
var pageBody = document.querySelector('body');
var jobRoleSelect = document.getElementById('title');
console.log(jobSelected);
var jobSelected = jobRoleSelect.options[jobRoleSelect.selectedIndex].value;
var basicSection = document.querySelector('basic');
console.log(basicSection);


// Job Role section of the form. Reveal a text field when the "Other" option is selected from the "Job Role" drop down menu
if(jobSelected === 'other') {
    var otherText = document.createElement('input');
    // Add an text input field. Use the id of "other-title" 
    otherText.setAttribute('id', 'other-title');
    otherText.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    otherText.setAttribute('name', 'other_field');
    otherText.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Your Title');

    var otherLabel = document.createElement('label');
    otherLabel.setAttribute('for', 'other_field');
    otherLabel.innerHTML = 'other';

    basicSelection.appendChild(otherLabel);
    basicSelection.appendChild(otherText);
}
```

Comment: Where is your JS code called from? For your purposes it should be in a function called from a change event handler on the select element. To use `.querySelector()` to select an element with class `'basic'` you need to put a `.` before the class name, like `document.querySelector('.basic')`. Also, you can get the selected value of a select element more simply: just use `jobRoleSelect.value`, no need to go via the `.options` collection. (Also, unrelated to the problem you are having, the `for` attribute in your label should be set to the associate element's `id`, not its `name`.)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing `.` for the querySelector, I forgot about that.

I've attached the JS at the bottom of the body in my HTML. 

I know it's linked up okay as another feature is working okay. 

So I can just use: `var jobSelected = jobRoleSelect.value'

and then in the if condition, use `if(jobSelected === 'other')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up an event listener to listen for the "change" event that is fired when the user makes a selection from the dropdown menu. Also you are referencing "basicSelection" instead of "basicSection" in your if statement.

```js
'use strict';

var jobRoleSelect = document.getElementById('title');
var basicSection = document.getElementsByClassName('basic')[0];

document.getElementById("title").addEventListener("change", function(){
  var jobSelected = jobRoleSelect.options[jobRoleSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(jobSelected);
  
  if(jobSelected === 'other') {
    var otherText = document.createElement('input');
    // Add an text input field. Use the id of "other-title" 
    
    otherText.setAttribute('id', 'other-title');
    otherText.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    otherText.setAttribute('name', 'other_field');
    otherText.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Your Title');
    
    var otherLabel = document.createElement('label');
    otherLabel.setAttribute('for', 'other_field');
    otherLabel.innerHTML = 'Other:';

    basicSection.appendChild(otherLabel);
    basicSection.appendChild(otherText);
  }
});
```

```html
<fieldset class="basic">         
        <legend>Basic Info</legend>

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">

        <label for="mail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">

        <label>Job Role</label>
        <select id="title" name="user_title">
          <option value="full-stack js developer">Full Stack JavaScript Developer</option>
          <option value="front-end developer">Front End Developer</option>
          <option value="back-end developer">Back End Developer</option>
          <option value="designer">Designer</option>          
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>  
        </select>           
      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the JS you've shown is included at the end of the document body then it will run *once* when the page first loads. I assume what you actually want is to have it run in response to the user changing what is selected, in which case you need to wrap your code in a function and make that an event handler for the `change` event.

```
var jobRoleSelect = document.getElementById('title');
jobRoleSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // your other code here
});
```

Note also that **you need to allow for the user changing the selection to "Other", then changing it back to something else, then changing it to "Other" again,** that is, your function would need to be able to remove the text input if not required for the current selection.

But I think it would be a lot simpler to just include the text element and label in your html and hide and show them as needed:

```js
   var jobRoleSelect = document.getElementById('title');

jobRoleSelect.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var otherSelected = jobRoleSelect.value === 'other';
  var otherElements = document.querySelectorAll('.other');

  for (var i = 0; i < otherElements.length; i++) {
    if (otherSelected)
      otherElements[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    else
      otherElements[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="basic">
  <legend>Basic Info</legend>

  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">

  <label for="mail">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">

  <label>Job Role</label>
  <select id="title" name="user_title">
    <option value="full-stack js developer">Full Stack JavaScript Developer</option>
    <option value="front-end developer">Front End Developer</option>
    <option value="back-end developer">Back End Developer</option>
    <option value="designer">Designer</option>
    <option value="student">Student</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <label class="other hidden" for="other-title">Other</label>
  <input class="other hidden" type="text" id="other-title" name="other-field" placeholder='Your title'>
</fieldset>
```

I've given all (that is both) of the elements that need to be hidden or shown the `other` class, which means my code has to loop over them. You could instead wrap them in a div and just hide the div.

Note that I've done the hiding/showing via a class, which I add or remove via the elements' `.classList`. Unfortunately `.classList` isn't supported in IE<=9, but there is [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#JavaScript_shim_for_other_implementations), or of course you can just set the `style.display` directly or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You have so many errors in your code. But i have figured them out and came out with the solution. Use this

```
<fieldset class="basic">         
        <legend>Basic Info</legend>

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">

        <label for="mail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">

        <label>Job Role</label>
        <select id="title" name="user_title">
          <option value="full-stack js developer">Full Stack JavaScript Developer</option>
          <option value="front-end developer">Front End Developer</option>
          <option value="back-end developer">Back End Developer</option>
          <option value="designer">Designer</option>          
          <option value="student">Student</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>  
        </select>           
      </fieldset>
      <script>
'use strict';

// Hold DOM elements for easy access
var pageBody = document.querySelector('body');
var jobRoleSelect = document.getElementById('title');
//console.log(jobSelected);
var basicSelection = document.querySelector('.basic');
//console.log(basicSection);

jobRoleSelect.onchange = function(){
    var jobSelected = jobRoleSelect.options[jobRoleSelect.selectedIndex].value;
// Job Role section of the form. Reveal a text field when the "Other" option is selected from the "Job Role" drop down menu
if(jobSelected == 'other') {
    console.log('nice');
    var otherText = document.createElement('input');
    // Add an text input field. Use the id of "other-title" 
    otherText.setAttribute('id', 'other-title');
    otherText.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    otherText.setAttribute('name', 'other_field');
    otherText.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Your Title');

    var otherLabel = document.createElement('label');
    otherLabel.setAttribute('for', 'other_field');
    otherLabel.innerHTML = 'other';

    basicSelection.appendChild(otherLabel);
    basicSelection.appendChild(otherText);
}
}
</script>
```

Here is a work [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyj22236/)